# Delete request в react-day-picker

Tags: reactjs

Я использую `react-day-picker` ([multiple days](https://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/selected-multiple))

Задача - получать даты с сервера (и показывать их выделенными). При выборе новой даты отправлять POST запрос на сервер. При удалении - удалить с севера.

Я реализовал получения и отправку, но не могу реализовать удаление. Удаление происходит по ID, но я не могу привязать ID к нужной дате. Если задать в запросе определенный id, то все работает.
API:

```
[
 {
    "stamp": "Mar 01, 2021",
    "id": 123
 },
 {
    "stamp": "Mar 01, 2021",
    "id": 123
 }
]
```

Код:

```
  this.state = {
        adsIssue: [],
    };
    this.handleDayClick = this.handleDayClick.bind(this);

    componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`MyURL/?id=${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(res => {
            return res;
        })
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    adsIssue: result.data.map((issue) => (new Date(issue.stamp))),
                });
            }
        )
        .catch(err => {
            return err
        })
    }
    handleDayClick(day, { selected }) {
    const { adsIssue } = this.state;
    const selectedDate = adsId.map((issue) => (issue.id));
    const data = {
        scroll_id: this.props.match.params.id,
        stamp: moment(day).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    };

    if (selected) {
        const selectedIndex = adsIssue.findIndex(selectedDay =>
            DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
        );
        adsIssue.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
        axios
            .delete(`My URL`, {params: {id: 123}}) //Hardcode is work!
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

    } else {
        adsIssue.push(day);
        axios
            .post(`MyUrl/?id=`, data)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    this.setState({ adsIssue });
}

    render() {
        return (
        <React.Fragment>
                        <DayPicker
                        selectedDays={this.state.adsIssue}
                        onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
                    />
        </React.Fragment>
        )

}
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.